# Probability that the $(n+1)$th dart is farther away from the center than the first dart

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This is an extension of [Dart Throw Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523507/dart-throw-probability) from "A Practice Guide To Quantitative Finance Interviews." Now we extend the problem to a generic $n+1$ darts, where we are given (1) Dart #1 is thrown closest to the center (2) Dart #2 to $n$ is thrown further from the center than the 1st dart.

What is the probability that the Dart #(n+1) is farther from the center than the first dart?

This question is equivalent to asking what is the probability that the $n+1-th$ dart is not the best among $n+1$ darts or the complement of "what is the probability that the $n+1$-th dart is the best among the $n+1$ darts.

When $n$ is large, doing the sequence enumeration or the integration in Graham Kemp's answer isn't practical. The author of this book provided an explanation that I'm struggling to understand:

[image]

This is what I understand:

(1) If we let $D_i$ denote the radial distance from the center of the i-th dart, then $D_i$ and $D_j$ are independent for $i \neq j$ and $i,j \in \{1,\cdots, n+1\}$, i.e., each dart's location on the board is independent.

(2) The event $D_i > D_1$ and $D_j > D_1$ are NOT independent any $i,j$ such that $i \neq j$ and $i \neq 1 \neq j$, i.e., knowing that a dart is further from the center than the first dart affects the knowledge of whether another dart is further from the center than the first dart.

(3) $D_k$ is independent of all events $D_j > D_i$ where $i \neq j$, $j \neq k$, $i \neq k$, i.e., where the k-th dart lands does not depend on the ordering of all darts (excluding k).

(1)-(3) are basically what the solution states, if I understand correctly. What I don't understand is why the answer $\frac{n}{n+1}$ is valid and how it relates to (1)-(3). Could someone explain?

In addition, I feel like the solution $\frac{n}{n+1}$ doesn't use the information that Darts 2-n are further away from the center than the first dart. If we neglect this information and instead ask the question "We will throw $n+1$ darts, what is the probability that the last dart is not the best given that each dart's radial location is IID, but we aren't given any information about the ordering of the first $n$ darts when we throw the n+1 dart?" I feel like the answer to this question is also $\frac{n}{n+1}$?

## another edit (basically summarizing my comments below)

I seem to have come to the conclusion that conditioning on the fact that $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$ does not change the answer. There are $(n+1)!$ permutations. $n!$ of these permutations will have the $(n+1)-th$ dart as the closest to the center. $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n+1}$, and  $1-\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}$. So we arrive at the same conclusion without conditioning on $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$. Now if we were to condition on this, we reduce the number of total permutations by $\frac{2}{3}$, but we also reduce the number of permutations where the $(n+1)-th$ dart is the best by $\frac{2}{3}$. So the probability is unchanged, i.e., $\frac{\frac{2}{3}n!}{\frac{2}{3}(n+1)!}  = \frac{1}{n+1}$. Actually, the reduction by $\frac{2}{3}$ isn't correct, it's only correct for the case of 4 darts. The reduction factor should be a function of $n$, but both the numerator and denominator are reduced by this reduction factor. I'll come back and edit when I figured out the general reduction factor.

I believe the reduction factor is $\frac{(n+1)! - (n! + (n-1)!)}{(n+1)!}$.
I found this by considering permutations of the set $\{D_1, \cdots, D_{n+1}\}$. In order to satisfy the condition that $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$, $D_1$ must be the first in the sequence or it must be the second in the sequence given that $D_{n+1}$ is the first in the sequence. We see that there are $n! + (n-1)!$ instances of this. Hence the total number of permutations is reduced by the factor $\frac{(n+1)! - (n! + (n-1)!)}{(n+1)!}$. Now if we were to consider the total number of permutations where the $(n+1)-th$ dart is the best and condition on $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$, this would require that all sequences look like $(D_{n+1}, D_1, \text{any permutation of } \{D_2, \cdots, D_n\})$. So there are $(n-1)!$ permutations of this. So the total number of permutations where the $(n+1)-th$ dart is the best and conditioned on $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$ is reduced by $\frac{n! - (n-1)!}{n!}$, which is $=\frac{(n+1)! - (n! + (n-1)!)}{(n+1)!}$

Comment: I think you are making it more difficult than it needs to be... Under any reasonable interpretation of the problem, when throwing $n+1$ darts, the order of the darts in relation to which is closest to the center is going to be such that each permutation is equally likely to occur.  Rather than talking about darts, we can just rephrase this in terms of permutations.  Rephrased in that context, we are looking at permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ where $\sigma(1)<\sigma(i)$ for all $2\leq i\leq n$ and we ask the probability that $\sigma(n+1)<\sigma(1)$ given this knowledge.

Comment: It should be clear that $\sigma(n+1)<\sigma(1)$ if and only if $\sigma(n+1)=1$ which occurs $\frac{1}{n+1}$ of the time and does not occur the remaining $\frac{n}{n+1}$ of the time.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think this is what I was thinking along these lines in the last paragraph of my OP that I edited in, but the main difference is I feel like I could arrive at the same conclusion without conditioning on that $\sigma(i) > \sigma(1)$ for all $2 \leq i \leq n$. For example, if we neglect this condition and consider 3 darts:, we have the following permutations (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (2, 1, 3), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2), (3, 2, 1). Note that the ordering (x, y, z) means that Dart x is the closest, Dart z is the farthest, and Dart z is in the middle. (Continuing the comment)

Comment: @JMoravitz Here we see that Dart 3 is the best 2 out of 6 times, hence Dart 3 is not the best 4 out of 6 times. So we arrive at the same conclusion without conditioning on that $\sigma(i) > \sigma(1)$ for all $ 2 \leq i \leq n$. If we were to condition on this, the sequences would be reduced to (1, 2, 3), (1, 3, 2), (3, 1, 2). Which gives us that 3 is the best 2 out of 3 times, which is the same answer as not conditioning on this fact? And I think this thinking extends to any $n$.

Comment: @JMoravitz In general, for any $n$, it appears that conditioning on $\sigma(i) > \sigma(1)$ for all $2 \leq i \leq n$ reduces the set of sequences we need to consider by $\frac{2}{3}$. And it also reduces the set of sequences where the $n+1$ dart is the best by $\frac{2}{3}$. So it seems conditioning on this fact or not does not change the answer. The relative proportions that $n+1$ is the best is always the same.

Comment: Your “another edit” is essentially what I would have given as an answer.

Comment: @DavidK Would it be correct for me to say that the question providing us the condition that $D_{2,\cdots,n} > D_1$ is a red herring?

Comment: I don't know I'd call it a red herring so much as I'd call it a rephrasing.  The original phrasing of the problem is "$D_{2,\dots,n}$ are all throws worse than $D_1$.  Given this, what is the probability that $D_{n+1}>D_1$?"  That $D_{2,\dots,n}$ are all worse than $D_1$ is an equivalent statement to saying that $D_1$ is the best throw among the first $n$ throws.  You could have stated it as "$D_1$ is the best throw", or you could have stated it as "$D_{2,\dots,n}$ are all worse throws than $D_1$" or you could have said both, all of these choices giving the same information.

Comment: What is important here is to distinguish between the problem of asking the probability that $D_1>D_{n+1}$ given this information, which leads to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ that $D_{n+1}$ is closer, versus asking for that probability given no information which leads to $\frac{1}{2}$ that $D_{n+1}$ is closer than $D_1$ (*but not necessarily the closest overall*).

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't realize the last part you stated. So if we ask the question "A person will throw $n+1$ darts, where the position of each dart on the board is IID, what is the probability that the $n+1$ dart is closer to the center than dart 1?" Then the answer to this would be $\frac{1}{2}$ because we're essentially 
 disregarding Darts 2-n? Now if the question was changed to "What is the probability that the $(n+1)-th$ dart is the best among $n+1$ darts?" This would give us the the answer in the underlying problem? I often get confused with wording in probability questions

Comment: It's the sunrise problem / rule of succession with n-1 observations. I can't really follow the proof, but it's fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thorough answer with fleshed out probability-theoretic arguments.

$D_1,\ldots,D_{n+1}$ are iid random variables which measure the distance of each throw to the center. We naturally assume that $P(\{D_1=D_2\})=0$ (this is the case e.g., when the underlying distribution of $D_1$ is continuous). As a consequence $P\big(\bigcap_{i\neq j} \{D_i\neq D_j\}\big)=1.$

The question is to compute
$P\big(\{D_{n+1}>D_1\} \big| \{D_{n}>D_1\}\cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big)$,
i.e., the ratio
$$ \frac{P\big(\{D_{n+1}>D_1\} \cap \{D_{n}>D_1\}\cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big)}{P\big( \{D_{n}>D_1\}\cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big)}.$$

---

It suffices to compute the numerator. The denominator will then follow by replacing $n+1$ with $n$. Note that
$$\begin{align}
P\big(\{D_{n+1}>D_1\} \cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big) 
&= P\big(\{D_1 < \min(D_2,\ldots,D_{n+1})\} \big)
\\&= P\big(\{D_1 < \min(D_2,\ldots,D_{n+1})\} \cap \bigcap_{i\neq j} \{D_i\neq D_j\} \big)
\\&= P\big(\bigsqcup_{\sigma \in Sym(\{2,\ldots,n+1\}) }
    \{D_1 < D_{\sigma(2)}<\ldots < D_{\sigma(n+1)}\}  \big)
\\&= \sum_{\sigma \in Sym(\{2,\ldots,n+1\}) } P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{\sigma(2)}<\ldots < D_{\sigma(n+1)}\}  \big)
,
\end{align}
$$
where $Sym(\{2,\ldots,n+1\}$ is the set of permutations on $\{2,\ldots,n+1\}$.

For each fixed $\sigma$, by the iid assumption, the vector
$(D_1,D_{\sigma(2)},\ldots, D_{\sigma(n+1)})$
has the same distribution as
$(D_1,D_{2},\ldots, D_{n+1})$. Consequently,
$$P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{\sigma(2)}<\ldots < D_{\sigma(n+1)}\}  \big) 
= P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{2}<\ldots < D_{n+1}\}  \big),$$
and
$P\big(\{D_{n+1}>D_1\} \cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big) = n! \, P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{2}<\ldots < D_{n+1}\}  \big).$

Similarly,
$$\begin{align}
1&= P\big(\bigsqcup_{\sigma \in Sym(\{1,\ldots,n+1\}) }
    \{D_{\sigma(1)} < D_{\sigma(2)}<\ldots < D_{\sigma(n+1)}\}  \big)
\\&= (n+1)! \, P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{2}<\ldots < D_{n+1}\}  \big)
,
\end{align}
$$
thus $P\big(
    \{D_1 < D_{2}<\ldots < D_{n+1}\}  \big) = \frac 1{(n+1)!}$
and finally
$$P\big(\{D_{n+1}>D_1\} \cap \ldots\cap\{D_{2}>D_1\} \big) = \frac {n!}{(n+1)!} = \frac 1{n+1}.$$

---

The ratio we are interested in is therefore $$\frac{1/(n+1)}{1/n} = \frac{n}{n+1}.$$