# What is wrong with my reasoning? (Probability third dart thrown is greater than first)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Jason throws two darts at a dartboard, aiming for the center. The second dart lands farther from the center than the first. If Jason throws a third dart aiming for the center, what is the probability that the third throw is further from the center than the first? Assume Jason's skillfulness is constant.

My (wrong) answer is 100%. Consider the positive real numbers indicating the distance to the center of the board. We randomly place the first and second dart anywhere on this number line. These darts will be at a finite number, for example maybe they're at 1 million & 1 trillion respectively. However, because the dartboard and number line is infinite, the probability that the third dart is closer to the origin than the first dart is going to be 0.

I don't understand what's wrong with my reasoning. Problem is stated here: [Dart Throw Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523507/dart-throw-probability)

Comment: If you only care about distance from the centre then radius is a randomly distributed variable from 0 to radius of the board (assuming it hits)

Comment: The distance from a dart to the center is an interval $[0,r]$, where $r$ is the radius.  It is not the entire real line.

Comment: @StackOverflowOfficial You assume the dartboard to be infinite, which is probably impossible.

Comment: Even if you do imagine $J$ is throwing darts at the real line, you can't imagine that he is uniformly likely to throw it anywhere on the reals.  There is no uniform distribution on the entire real line, after all.