# Dart game question - probability 3rd dart is further from center than the first

Tags: probability

I'm revisiting a problem I saw years ago. The problem is:

Suppose there is a dart board. The player throws 3 darts, independently, with equal skill on each throw. Second dart lands further from the center than the first dart. What is the probability that the 3rd dart lands further from the center than the first dart.

The standard textbook answer is to enumerate all 6 possible outcomes. Then condition on the second dart being further than the first, which gives us 3 possible outcomes and out of those 3, 2 of those have the third dart being further from the center than the first. This makes sense to me and is the answer I got in the beginning.

But now I'm rethinking this problem and I feel like the above answer seems to suggest that throwing the second dart further from the center than the first dart somehow makes us less skillful on the third throw. So I can't seem to wrap my head around why the answer makes sense from a practical perspective. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart Throw Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1523507/dart-throw-probability)

Comment: Absent info on the 2nd dart, you would expect the probability that the 3rd dart is farther away to be (1/2).  The info on the 2nd dart indicates that the 1st dart has been thrown more skillfully than normal.  This is intuitively consistent with the probability that the 3rd dart is farther away changing from (1/2) to (2/3).  In effect, the info of the 2nd dart has indicated that it is more likely than not that the relative skill in the 3rd dart is less than the relative skill of the 1st dart.

Answer (score 0):

> the above answer seems to suggest that throwing the second dart further from the center than the first dart somehow makes us more skillful on the third throw.

The *third* throw's distribution is unaffected, but the *condition* does impose a bias on the *first throw*.

Let $X, Y, Z$ be three iid non-negative real-valued random variables, representing the distance from the centre of the board on each of three dart throws.

The condition of $X\leqslant Y$, biases the distribution of $X$ towards smaller values.  It is more likely to be closer to the center than you would otherwise expect.

$$\mathsf P(X\leqslant x\mid X\leqslant Y)\geqslant\mathsf P(X\leqslant x)$$

Therefore that condition *shall raise* the probability for $X\leqslant Z$.

$$\mathsf P(X\leqslant Z\mid X\leqslant Y)\geqslant \mathsf P(X\leqslant Z)$$

Which is precisely what you found :

$$\dfrac 23\gt \dfrac 1 2$$

Comment: sorry, just saw this. I commented this above "hmm I feel like "What's the probability that the third dart is closest to the center OUT OF 3 DARTS?" is a different question than "What's the probability that the third dart is closer to the center THAN THE FIRST DART?" The former conditions on all 3 darts, while the latter conditions on just the first and third darts. Isn't the question in the OP about the latter question? That's how I interpreted it " I understand the 3rd throw's distribution is unaffected, but the "imposing a bias on the first throw" part seems to be a matter of interpretation?

Comment: Since the underlying question is "What is the probability that the 3rd dart is further from the center than the first," I feel we can interpret this as not conditioning on the 2nd dart's location?

Comment: The full question is: "Suppose there is a dart board. The player throws 3 darts, independently, with equal skill on each throw. **Second dart lands further from the center than the first dart.** What is the probability that the 3rd dart lands further from the center than the first dart."  @24n8

Answer (score 0):

You see three darts on the dartboard (you didn't see the throws). What's the probability that the third dart is closest to the center? That probability (from your point of view) is $\frac13$, under the assumption of independence and equal skill of the throws.

Someone who saw the throws mentions that they remember that the first throw was closer to the center than the second throw.

That new information should not change your assessment of the probability that the third dart is the closest to the center--that probability (in your estimation) is still $\frac13$. However, the second dart can't be closest from the extra information that you received. So the remaining probability goes to the first dart--probability that the first dart is closest to the center is $\frac23$.

In other words, by being closer than the second dart, the first dart captures the second dart's probability of being closest.

Comment: hmm I feel like "What's the probability that the third dart is closest to the center OUT OF 3 DARTS?" is a different question than "What's the probability that the third dart is closer to the center THAN THE FIRST DART?" The former conditions on all 3 darts, while the latter conditions on just the first and third darts. Isn't the question in the OP about the latter question? That's how I interpreted it